# Eclipse RAP 2.0 Double Click on TableViewer/TreeViewer Unresponsive on IE8

Tags: eclipse-rap

I am working on RAP 2.0 with IE8. Many time I double click on treeviewer node or item on tableviwer, it triggers no DoubleClickListener event. However if I made 3 clicks in a row, it will trigger the DoubleClickListener. It is working fine on Firefox and Chrome. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If the behavior differs between IE and other browsers, it is likely a bug in RAP. However, it works fine for me, so there might be something in your application code that triggers this issue. I recommend you create a small RAP application (just an entrypoint) that demonstrates the issue and post it either on the [RAP newsgroup](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/eclipse.technology.rap) or [RAP Bugzilla](http://eclipse.org/rap/bugs/).